# Is there a Linux equivalent of SetupDiGetClassDevs function

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have written a c++ program to search PCI devices in Windows using HDEVINFO objects and the SetupDiGetClassDevs function.

Are there Linux equivalents for these functions? 
I will be using Kubuntu, so KDE-specific and/or Ubuntu-specific solutions are fine.
An example piece of code would be even more appreciated ;-)

Thank you

Comment: On Google, I found this link: "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9DNuaa6E9_0J:www.cs.ru.ac.za/research/g98t4414/static/papers/oscomposr.pdf+&cd=3&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=be".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get pretty much any information about connected PCI devices by iterating through /sys/devices/pci* directories.

For example,

```
cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/subsystem_vendor
```

would return the Vendor ID for that device.

Overall, I would suggest looking at contents of /proc and /sys filesystems, that's pretty much everything you can use in userspace. For some more interesting stuff consider writing kernel modules instead (that's not the topic for SO question, I'd suggest to read Linux Device Drivers of the latest edition).

UPD1: Yeah, this is not really a function, as someone would surely point out, but reading and writing these files doesn't seem really difficult, just a different approach compared to Windows.

UPD2: for kernel module approach, I'd suggest googling the information about `pci_register_driver` function, and all that comes with it.

UPD3: even more, for userspace there is usually a way to work directly with PCI devices resources - just open `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/resourceX`, where X is the number of corresponding BAR. These files can be read and written as you like, as long as you know the correct offset.

Comment: I am doing all these operations in the userspace

Comment: Well, then stuff, provided by /sys/devices should be enough for you.